# How to index the result of a mySql query as an array of array?

Tags: php, mysql

If I need to select and use information of every element of a table in a database the procedure would be this:

```
$query = "...mySql query...";
$query_result = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
```

Then if I wished to access the fields of the result I would use the function mysql_fetch_array() and access them like this:

```
$query_result_array = mysql_fetch_array($query_result);
echo $query_result_array['field_1'];
....
echo $query_result_array['field_i'];
....
```

But since more elements could be returned by the query I would like to access every single of them with an array indexed from 0 to mysql_num_rows($query_result).

As an example:

```
echo $query_result_array['field_i'][0];
....
echo $query_result_array['field_i'][mysql_num_rows($query_result)];
```

should print for every selected element of the table the value of field i.

Is there a function that will do the job for me?
If not, any suggestions on how to do it?

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be an alternative

```
$res = mysql_query("..SQL...");
$arr = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $arr[] = $row;
}
var_dump($arr);
```

Or

```
$res = mysql_query("..SQL...");
for
(
    $arr = array(); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res); 
    $arr[] = $row
);
var_dump($arr);
```

Comment: when will the while loop end?

Comment: After fetches all results from your SQL query. When `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns `false` means there are no more rows, then exits.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is such a method; you have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

try with something like:

```
$res = mysql_query("..mySql query...");
$arr = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $query_result_array[] = $row;
}
```

then you access your data like:

```
echo $query_result_array[0]['field_i'];
```

Answer (score 1):

based on 2 previous answers, those authors assuming that usual SO author is familiar with such a thing as creating a function

```
function sqlArr($sql) { return an array consists of 
  $ret = array();
  $res = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql);
  if ($res) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
      $ret[] = $row;
    }
  }
  return $ret;
}

$array = sqlArr("SELECT * FROM table");
foreach ($array as $row) {
  echo $row['name'],$row['sex'];
}
```

this resulting array have different structure from what you asked, but it is way more convenient too. 
if you still need yours unusual one, you have to tell how you gonna use it